# Xampp and symfony on windows7

Tags: php, symfony, xampp

I'm quite new with symfony and i'm trying to develop a base web application.

I install and configured symfony on my pc (windows 7 64bit) following the documentation and all works fine.

I run the server with command line (`php bin/console server:run`) and test the application in browser successfully.

Then iwould like to move the symfony folder under my local Xampp (`xampp\htdocs\symfony\myproject`) installation that i use for php development since now.

My problem is that when i run `localhost\symfony\myproject\web` the symfony welcome page is shown but if i modify the `index.html.twig` template no change are displayed.

Some routing problem? `vhosts` config?

Comment: Formatting and grammar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
localhost\symfony\myproject\web\app_dev.php
```

since `localhost\symfony\myproject\web` is the prod url and has some cache, which may "hide" your modification

Comment: Thanks Sylvain, your answer lead me to re-read the documentation about controller but i don't understand how using xampp affect to the url mapped for route. Using the build-in web server url _localhost:8000_ is route **/** and _localhost:8000/somepage_ is route **/somepage**. How i have to map _localhost/symfony/myproject/web/somepage_ in order to use app.php or app_dev.php?

Comment: localhost/symfony/myproject/web/app_dev.php/somepage

Comment: but it would be better to configure your vhost, check this : http://blog.servergrove.com/2012/06/01/setting-up-a-symfony2-project-using-mamp/

Comment: Thanks again ,i set a vhost and back studying. I think i have to set the same vhost on my production web server in order to not lost all route.